# Can MFC multithread program run in a parallel method?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I want to utilize multithread in MFC. I'm doing a little experiment to see if the program runs in a parallel method. I write two thread function like this:

```
UINT CMFCApplication2Dlg::thread01(LPVOID pParam)
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
        cout << "thread01111111111" << endl;

    t2 = clock();
    cout << "clock is " << t2 - t1 << endl;
    return 0;
}

UINT CMFCApplication2Dlg::thread02(LPVOID pParam)
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1 = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
        cout << "thread02222222222" << endl;


    t2 = clock();
    cout << "clock is " << t2 - t1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and call them and output into a console window:

```
AllocConsole();                     

    freopen("CONOUT$", "w+t", stdout);

    freopen("CONIN$", "r+t", stdin);  

    printf("Hello World！\n");         

    CWinThread *pThread01;
    CWinThread *pThread02;
    pThread01 = AfxBeginThread(thread01, this, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
    pThread02 = AfxBeginThread(thread02, this, 0, 0, 0, NULL);
```

When running two threads together, the count is 118020; When running single thread, the count is 60315; When put two loops in the same thread in a serial way, I get 102795.

I used to think the compiler could optimize multiple-thread to execute in parallel automatically, but it seems like single core multithread concurrency does. It doesn't reduce runtime. The CPU I used has 4 cores. What should I do to run threads in different core parallel to achieve high performance?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. It follows the "multithreading is the answer, what is the question?" pattern. If you want better answers, you need to ask better questions (i.e. write better test code). You can only ask better questions, if you know the answers already.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your point exactly. If you mean the test code is too awful, It's maybe because I haven't received formal CS training. You can refer lacks in my code directly.

Comment: Your code uses a global resource (`std::cout`, presumably) that provides no guarantees with respect to output ordering when accessed from multiple threads. Using the observed output order as the base for logical reasoning is thus not very useful. You cannot deduce reliable results based on unreliable input. You need a good book on concurrency, and a good book on CPU architectures. Plus, a good book on MFC, if you wish to use MFC.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. Well, i don't want to dive into MFC because I've heard it's quite old. So is there any other efficient GUI supported multithread worthy of learning? Is the concurrency runtime in MSDN referred by a answer good to learn? Or any other recommendation?

Comment: Anything (including MFC) is good to learn, so that you can make judicious decision. Making a decision based on that you've heard that some technology is old, is not a good decision, and only the right decision by pure luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both threads are trying to use a shared resource (`std::cout`) at the same time. The system has to serialize output at one point so most of the time one of the threads will wait for the other one to finish writing. This is called *synchronization*. When you are using threads for performance improvements, you want to minimize the time spent for synchronization as much as possible, because during this time the threads can't do useful work.

Try to replace `cout` in the inner loop by a lengthy calculation, and only use `cout` at the end to print the final result, so the compiler cannot optimize the calculation away (without `cout` it could, because the calculation would have no observable effect).

Also, `std::clock` lacks precision for profiling. I recommend to use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) instead which usually is implemented using `QueryPerformanceCounter()` on the Windows platform. This is the best you can get on Windows.

Try this:

```
INT CMFCApplication2Dlg::thread01(LPVOID pParam)
{
    using myclock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    auto t1 = myclock::now();

    std::int64_t first = 0, second = 1, result = 0;
    for( std::int64_t i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i )
    {
         result = first + second;
         first = second;
         second = result;
    }

    auto t2 = myclock::now();   
    std::chrono::duration<double> td = t2 - t1;  // duration in seconds

    std::cout << "result is " << result << '\n'
              << "clock is " << std::fixed << std::setprecision( 6 ) << td.count() << " s" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Make sure the calculation is not too simple, because the optimizer is pretty clever and may turn your O(n) algorithm into O(1) for instance. It may even do the entire calculation at compile time and only assign a constant at runtime. 
To avoid that, you could read the number of loop iterations from `cin` instead. Though this wasn't necessary when testing the above code on MSVC 2017 even with  full optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your careful explanation. After test I get the same runtime between two threads and single. I have obeserved runtime will increase with threads adding(not exceed number of logical cores). And I use 
 'SetThreadAffinityMask' to force threads run on the same core but fail, is it because system distribute automatically?

Answer (score -1):

Read about concurrency runtime. It can help you without the headache: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx

Comment: How does that address the question being asked?

Comment: The concurrency runtime mechanism can make the multi-threading more simple to write and easy to use.That is what he wanted to do.

Comment: Bogus. The OP was asking, why their multi-threaded application seemingly doesn't run multiple threads in parallel. It does, though, it's just that their test is wrong, and they draw the wrong conclusions. Switching to a different multi-threading framework won't help here. -1 for being useless. And wrong.